# Wix and XmlSerialization: Colon character is getting encrypted to x003A

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, wix

After spending some time looking for how to solve this problem, found the solution and decided to post this respected forum, giving deserved credit.

The problem: the serialization of **XmlElementAttribute** below generated the following content in WXS file then:

```
[XmlElementAttribute("bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication")]
public WixStandardBootstrapperApplication WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
{ get; set; }

<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
   <bal_x003A_WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" SupressOptionsUI="yes" />
</ BootstrapperApplicationRef >
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution found at: **http://forums.asp.net/post/3149628.aspx**. Like this:

Serialization code:

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter (wxsBundleFileName) ;
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(wx.GetType());

XmlSerializerNamespaces XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", " http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
ns.Add("bal", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension") ;

xs.Serialize(tw, wx, ns);
```

The correct code is serialization class is:

```
[XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "WixStandardBootstrapperApplication", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension")]
public WixStandardBootstrapperApplication WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
{ get; set; }
```

Ready!

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
   <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="" SupressOptionsUI="yes" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```